# Stack overflow on recursive method when the counter begins at 1

Tags: java, recursion

I've written a program to read in a text file containing a matrix of 1s and 0s that will loop recursively to identify all unique four-connected regions (regions connected by moving up, down, left, right). I then replace the 1s in each region with an identifier number, however when I begin the counter for the replacement values at 1 I get a stack overflow error. I've worked around this while building my recursive method by just starting at 2 and then going back after everything is finished and decrementing all the region values by 1 so that the region counters start at 1 in the output. This works and my output is correct, but this feels like a lazy solution.

I know I need a way to identify if a 1 has already been identified, this would allow me to replace an area with 1s and still be able to properly read through the grid, but I am unsure of any way to see if an element is a member of an object. I've attempted to build a series of if-else statements to identify the very first 1 encountered and to loop from there, but when I hit that region again I either get a stack overflow error or bizarre outputs such as every number in the first region (which should be replaced by new 1s) being a different number. Would it be smarter to write a second recursive method to handle the very first 1 encountered, or does the fact I start at 2 and then later decrement all values really make the program so ugly?

```
/**
 * Scans the grid for 1s, calling the designateRegions method when unique
 * 1s are found.
 */
public static void findRegions() {
    int region = 2;//the counter variable in question
    for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nCols; j++) {
            if (grid[i][j] == 1) {
                //Ensure the value isn't part of a known region
                if (j-1 >= 0 && grid[i][j-1] >= 1) {
                    grid[i][j] = grid[i][j-1];
                } else if (i-1 >= 0 && grid[i-1][j] >= 1) {
                    grid[i][j] = grid[i-1][j];
                } else {//if 1 is unique
                    Regions regionObject = new Regions(region);//instantiate a Regions object
                    regionCountList.add(regionObject);//add new Regions object to arraylist
                    designateRegions(grid, i, j, region, regionObject);//call recursive method designateRegions
                    region++;
                }//end nested if-else block
            }//end outer if statement
        }//end inner for loop
    }//end outer for loop

    //this is stupid
    for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nCols; j++) {
            if (grid[i][j] > 1) {
                grid[i][j] = grid[i][j] - 1;//drop the value of each region by 1
            }//end if statement
        }//end inner for loop
    }//end outer for loop

}//end findRegions method

/**
 * Loops recursively to identify four-connected regions of 1s and change the
 * value of the elements in the newly identified region.
 * @param grid the 2d integer array containing the grid to be scanned
 * @param r the row position
 * @param c the column position
 * @param region the identifier value for the region
 * @param regionObject the object associated with each region
 */
private static void designateRegions(Integer[][] grid, int r, int c, int region, Regions regionObject) {
    if (grid[r][c] == 0) { //base case
    } else if (grid[r][c] == 1) {
        grid[r][c] = region;//switch value of the 1 with appropriate region identifier
        regionObject.regionCount++;
        if (r - 1 >= 0) {
            designateRegions(grid, r - 1, c, region, regionObject);//move up
        }
        if ((r + 1) < nRows) {
            designateRegions(grid, r + 1, c, region, regionObject);//move down
        }
        if ((c + 1) < nCols) {
            designateRegions(grid, r, c + 1, region, regionObject);//move right
        }
        if (c - 1 >= 0) {
            designateRegions(grid, r, c - 1, region, regionObject);//move left
        }
    }
}//end findRegions method
```

Comment: I don't understand all these closing votes. The question is very specific, it talks about a technique of marking visited cells, and it has a working code (stack overflow happens when OP tries to refactor the code).

Comment: I cannot imagine a way to distinguish between a 1 identifying first region from a 1 identifying a raw cell. But such a question should better be asked on CodeReview.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight You are right that it is very specific. Unfortunately, the question is phrased in a way that will elicit debate instead of answers based on facts. Usually it is a warnign sign when you phrase your question like "Would it be smarter...?". I am voting to close until it is re-phrased in a less opinion based manner...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You correctly identified the problem: the recursive code needs to mark each grid element that has been visited to prevent the program from chasing its own tail.

Marking the visited cells with a different value (2) is a valid strategy. Another possibility would be passing around a separate grid of `boolean[nRows][nCols]`s with cells that have a `true` in them identify the visited cells.

I think that your solution is cleaner, because it does not require allocating any additional memory.

Comment: So my approach is valid? I figured it would be looked at with scorn. A second grid is a great solution I never thought about, but the memory and time used would probably be an issue as you said (this is for a data structures class and everything is about time complexity with my professor). If this is an honest approach, I may just keep it. I just assumed people wouldn't like what I did.

Comment: Thanks for the help, by the way. I really appreciate it.